# What are DShellFolderViewEvents and DShellFolderViewEvents_Event?

Tags: vb.net, windows-shell

The names make it sound like some sort of event handler.
Both were identified as an interface from `Shell32` using the code below: 
I can't find either of these in the MSDN libraries.  Google returned some pages with code where they appeared, but I didn't see anything that really described the interface.

```
Public Sub ListTypes()
    Dim NS As String = "Shell32"
    For Each t As Type In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        If (t.IsClass Or t.IsInterface) And t.Namespace = NS Then
            Debug.Print(t.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definition in `ShlDisp.h` it appears to simply be a thin wrapper around [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx) with a different GUID.

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("62112AA2-EBE4-11cf-A5FB-0020AFE7292D")
DShellFolderViewEvents : public IDispatch
{
};
```

It seems to be used in obtaining event notification from the shell - [Raymond Chen's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140922-00/?p=44013) has some example code.

Comment: Jonathan, looking at Raymond's code (and from the names of the interface) I would say yes, some sort of event handler.  I just can't find *any* documentation on it.... Thanks for the link!